# how to specify text enclosed in square brackets

Tags: java, regex, str-replace, replaceall

I have a string that contains multiple occurrences of text enclosed in square brackets that I need to remove such as:

10/21/2012 12:12:15 **[12:12:28]** Admitted Last,First (Card #555) at  Lobby Turnstile # 4 (IN) **[In]**  **[Noticed]**

I tried String.replaceAll, replaceFirst using the regex "\[.*\]" which removes all the texts between the first [ and last ] and I end up with

10/21/2012 12:12:15

I'm stuck on how to specify the expression.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try "\[.*?\]" - the extra "?" means the match is non-greedy so should stop at each "]" (untested, hence comment rather than answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use a non-greedy quantifier: `"\[.*?\]"`

or specifically exclude the close char: `"\[[^]]*\]"`

Comment: Perfect.  The non-greedy qualifier worked...Thanks.  

rec = rec.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "");